# Video lectures on Partial Differential Equations

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, online-resources

Would anyone happen to know any introductory video lectures / courses on partial differential equations? I have tried to find it without success (I found, however, on ODEs).

It does not have to be free material, but something not to expensive would be nice.

Comment: I assume you've checked here: http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm but I'm gonna leave it here anyway

Comment: Yes, I've checked it, but thank you nonetheless!

Comment: Note for the record, I did not find any PDE videos on the MIT opencourseware site. There might be some PDE stuff mixed into some of Gilbert Strang's courses, but that is mostly numerical methods and not an introduction to PDEs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is answer to your Question .Complete course of PDE are available there

http://nptel.ac.in/courses.php

These lectures are  there in youtube channel 'nptel" but contents and syllabus can be seen from link above

Comment: The link doesn't work (as of October 2020).

Answer (score 3):

You can find a lecture on Hyperbolic Conservation Laws, given by Constantine Dafermos [here](http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=Curso-Hyperbolic-Conservation-Laws).

And [here](http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=escola-de-altos-estudos-unique-continuation-and-nonlinear-dispersive-equations) a course on unique continuation and nonlinear dispersive equations, given by Gustavo Ponce.

Comment: I think you mean Gustavo Ponce?

Comment: Valeu, Tomás. I was looking for something on a more introductory level, but I did not mention this. I will edit my post now. This should be interesting later, though. You would not happen to know if there are any PDE lectures in Portuguese by the way?

Comment: You are right @Jose27, I will fixt it, thank you.

Comment: @Akitirija, take a look in Impa's lectures. Most of them are in portuguese.

Answer (score 2):

Khan Academy is very good with teaching Differential Equations. You should check it out:

[Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations)

Comment: They cover PDEs?

Answer (score 1):

The best PDE introduction that I have found is by Dr. Pavel Grinfeld on youtube. The link is:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlXfTHzgMRUK56vbQgzCVM9vxjKxc8DCr

These are really really excellent. He starts with ODEs and then moves to PDEs. He covers the introduction to elliptic, hyperbolic,and parabolic PDEs, heat equation, separation of variables, and Fourier series. Unfortunately he does not cover other common topics like Sturm-Liouville problems and Green's functions, etc. But this is probably the best place to start. After that you can find individual videos on Green's functions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

May Be these Lectures will be useful to you

http://www.math.lamar.edu/faculty/maesumi/PDE1.html